# Application crash when open DataBase in JellyBean Emulator because cannot find the DBPath

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have always used the same code to create a DB from file in assets folder
now I have tried to run the same code in JellyBean 4.3 emulator and in this point

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String nomeDB) {
            super(context, nameDB, null, version);
            DB_NAME = nameDB;
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        ....
        }
```

the app crashes at this line

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
```

With a IOException

in addition Eclipse editor show me a warning to not hardcode /data/ path, so I  assume that there is a better way to write the PATH avoiding these issues

What is the right syntax to use in `DB_PATH` String to avoid possible issues with different devices?

Comment: If you're getting a NPE on the line you indicated, variable `context` is `null`.

Comment: @vikram I'm sorry was an IOException, I have edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Probably IOException in your case means its not finding the database file at referred path.
I would always go with Android inbuilt API methods rather than constructing path.

Following method is available in Context to give you database path.

```
public File getDatabasePath (String name)
```

> Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a database created
>   with openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)
>   is stored.

You can read on it on this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

DB_PATH = "//data//data/" + context.getPackageName() + "//databases//";

it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Same thing. I get exactly the same issue